# What is the regular Nexus 5X autonomy?

Tags: battery-life, nexus-5x

I bought a Google Nexus 5X a week ago, and I'm surprised by the autonomy. Being 100% charged at 9:00 AM, at ~7:00 PM the battery is empty. I use about an hour of Spotify a day and Facebook & Messenger are installed.

I run on a Android 6.0.1 that seems to be fully updated.

I can give it back to my reseller, but it is really an anomaly ?

Comment: A 10-hour life isn't too surprising, especially when Facebook & Messenger are known to eat up your battery very quickly. You can always go to Settings -> Battery, and check what's using up the majority of your battery.

Answer (score 1):

OH Facebook and messenger theirs your battery killers. plus anything using the net will kill it. i charge my 5X and im good for 3 days. I dont play games but i use it for some web browsing well away from home. also i listen to music on the device which dont eat the battery as bad

Answer (score 0):

For people who were wondering, after a product replacement and a few weeks of use, I had about 12 hours of autonomy with a regular use (without Facebook app but with Facebook Messenger).

Then, I installed the Android Nougat update in the same phone, and I now have about 1.5-2 days of the same use ! The autonomy is almost doubled.

It seems to be really dependant of the software optimization and the usage.